# Access pandas DataFrame in a loop to control indeces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 5053x5053 Pandas DataFrame that represents some kind of relations between exported products, indeces and columns are serial numbers and they are stored in a numpy array. I have another numpy array with only some of the 5053 serial numbers (they represent Green products). I'm interested in plotting and analizing the relations between products, given from the matrix values, distinguishing  between normal and green products. There is some function in Pandas to access the indeces and the columns in a loop to "control" if I'm dealing with a Green product or not?

```
products = genfromtxt('products.txt', delimiter='\n') #numpy array 5053,
greens = genfromtxt ('GreenList.txt', delimiter='\n') #numpy array with only green products
p-value = pd.DataFrame(data = p, index = products, columns = products) # DataFrame, p is a 5053x5053 numpy array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Pandas operations for indexing and selecting are vectorized, meaning the looping is done for you under the covers.

What you want to do sounds something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# fake data frame indexed by serial number.
x = pd.DataFrame(
  {
    'serial': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006],
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  })
x.set_index('serial', inplace=True)

green_serials = [1002, 1004, 1006]

# select by index values
x.loc[green_serials]

# output:
#         x
# serial
# 1002    2
# 1004    4
# 1006    6
```

Maybe, a boolean column indicating green/not-green might be helpful:

```
x['green'] = x.index.isin( green_serials )
```

```
        x  green
serial
1001    1  False
1002    2   True
1003    3  False
1004    4   True
1005    5  False
1006    6   True
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! I'll try it right away but should work.